# Generating a random date on the last day of the month

Tags: groovy

How to prepare a groovy script in which the result a random date on the last day of the month. range up from 2022-03-31 to 2050-01-31

**Example**

```
Possibilities
2022-03-31
2022-04-30
2022-05-31
and so on.
Result 2022-04-30.
```

I will be grateful for your help

I try:

```
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
def theValue =  formattedDate
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this on your own? Please share it, even if it isn't working.

Comment: I tried a few options but i have errors, I added an option that works and shows the today day.

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method for fun

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.YearMonth
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters
import java.util.stream.Collector
import java.util.stream.Collectors
import java.util.stream.Stream

def start = YearMonth.parse("2022-03")
def end = YearMonth.parse("2050-01")

Stream.iterate(start, s -> s.plusMonths(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(start, end) + 1)
        .map(m -> m.atEndOfMonth())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .shuffled()
        .head()
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses `java.time.LocalDate` methods to add to the first date a number of days (up to the number of days between the two dates). It then shifts that to the end of the month:

```
import java.time.*

def r = new Random();
def start = LocalDate.parse("2022-03-31") 
def end = LocalDate.parse("2050-01-31");

def randomEndDate = (start + r.nextInt((int) (end - start)))
         .plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
```